# With Glassfish, how to resolve https URL to http URL

Tags: glassfish

GlassFish 3.0.1 RHEL 6.5 MySQL 5.4

Hello all

I have a web app running under GlassFish/RHEL/MySQL where all of the software tiers (GlassFish/RHEL/MySQL) are on the same system. I have a (separate) DNS server which maps `mycompany.myserver.org` to `10.1.2.3`. I can resolve the server name with nslookup successfully so DNS is working. I can access the web app internally by using `http://10.1.2.3:8080/myapp/p=101`.

However, I want to use SSL and I want to access my app (internally) via https://mycompany.myserver.org/myapp/p=101.

How does one do this using GlassFish? In other words, how does one "map" `https://mycompany.myserver.org/myapp/p=101` and redirect/resolve it to `http://10.1.2.3:8080/myapp/p=101?`

Many thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `https` listener to glassfish either by using the admin console or by editing the `domain.xml`.

If you afterwards disable the `http` listener you can only access by `https`.

A redirect or proxy is not needed.

Please note that you can use port 443 (the default port for `https`) only if you run glassfish as root.

Comment: If true, can I not just use the http-listener-2 which is already setup by default for secure communications and change the port from the default 8181 to port 443?

Comment: Yes, you can use the http-listener-2 for this.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working.  Explain to me how a request to https- listener at port 443 is going to translate/know to go to http at 8080 without some redirection?  Do you have a GlassFish Admin Web page screen shot of what the https-listener configuration looks like?  (I am referring to https-listener but its really the secure http-listener-2 that is created by default -- I have changed the port from the default 8181 to 443.) Btw, thanks for taking the time to assist me.

Comment: Is a keytool self-signed cert needed first before https //mycompany.myserver.org/myapp/p=101 can be reached/rendered?

Comment: @tale852150 The http-listener-2 does not forward the request but serves it itself. If you simply deploy your application (witout further provisions) then it runs on both ports simultaniously. A key is not needed as the domain creation already creates a self signed key.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this GlassFish server is from another VM.  So this entire system is a clone but (of course) on a different IP address.  Wouldn't that nullify the generated key since the domain was created on another system, the system that my current system was cloned from?

Comment: @tale852150 yes, if you cloned the server then you have to create a new key with the correct DN.

Comment: And, since this was an inherited system, I do not know the keystore password.  Can I create a new password as follows?  1. Rename the file named "master-password" in your domain's folder to something else. It should then prompt you for the master password. If not, on the start-domain command, provide a file as: asadmin start-domain --user admin-user-name --passwordfile filename domain-name" where filename contents are:
AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin-password (the one you use for GUI)
AS_ADMIN_MASTERPASSWORD=changeit (this is the vanilla domain's default keystore password).

Comment: Got lucky.  The default password for keytool still worked.